# Перегрузка оператора + для сложения своего объекта и чисел

Tags: python

Хочу осуществить возможность перегрузить оператор +, таким способом, что бы возможно было к объекту добавлять объект, и к объекту добавлять число.

```
class Fff:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __add__(self,obj):
        return Fff(self.x + obj.x,self.y + obj.y)
    def __add__(self,v):
        return Fff(self.x + v,self.y + v)
    def show(self):
        print self.x,' : ',self.y

f1 = Fff(1,2)
f2 = Fff(5,5)

result = f1 + f2
result2 = f1 + 2

result.show()
result2.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Перегрузки функций в питоне нету. Но вы можете реализовать различное поведение функции в зависимости от типа переданного аргумента. Используйте нечто подобное вместо обеих ваших методов сложения.

```
def __add__(self, arg):
    if isinstance(arg, numbers.Number):
        return Fff(self.x + arg, self.y + arg)
    else:
        return Fff(self.x + arg.x, self.y + arg.y)
```

Comment: можно реализовать метод `__add__` как `_Fff_add(arg, fff)` функцию и [применить к ней `@functools.singledispatch` для разных типов](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24064102/4279) -- перегрузка для бедных. Единственное достоинство (что также можно недостатком считать), это то что можно поддержку для дополнительных типов, вне `Fff` добавлять (даже в другом модуле).

Comment: вместо `type(arg) is Type` лучше `isinstance(arg, Type)` если нет специальных обстоятельств первый вариант предпочитать. К примеру, [`isinstance(arg, numbers.Number)` (что для int, float, итд работает)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#implementing-the-arithmetic-operations)

Comment: @jfs, спасибо за ценное замечание. Подправил ответ